# Path-connectedness of a finite cell complex involving a wedge sum of circles

Tags: algebraic-topology, connectedness, cw-complexes, path-connected

The following is a result from Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology* text:

[image]

In various solutions to problems from the text that reference this corollary, it is stated that the space $X_G$ described above is path-connected. Why is this?

$X_G$ is certainly a CW complex, and it is known that a CW complex is path-connected if and only if it is connected. So, is there a relatively easy way to see that $X_G$ is connected, or a relatively easy way to see that $X_G$ is path-connected?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wedge sum itself is clearly path connected, and attaching discs to it isn't going to stop it being path connected.

I guess if you want a formal proof, suppose you have a point.  It's either the wedge point, or a point of one of the circles of the wedge sum, or a point on one of the discs.  If it's a point on a disc, take a line from that point to the boundary of the disc and you get a path from your point to a point on the wedge sum.  Then take a path along that circle to the wedge point, and all together you have a path from an arbitrary point of $X_G$ to the wedge point.

But then you can get a path between any two points by going from your starting point, to the wedge point, to your finish point.